# Ask Centos to downgrade the a relevant package

Tags: centos, yum

I recently encountered a problem wherein the update package manager(confirmed this on yum history) just updated the zeromq package which was [4.0.5-4.el7](https://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=4716) to [4.1.4-5.el7](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/34468753/dir/redhat_el_7/com/zeromq-devel-4.1.4-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)

Now, this has resulted in some breaking changes.

I'm trying to downgrade the zeromq to version 4.0.5-4.el7 but every time it does that

I get this

```
sudo yum install zeromq.x86_64-4.0.5-4.el7
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package zeromq.x86_64-4.0.5-4.el7 available
```

Now, I have a couple of question.

1. How do I get the older version of zeromq back (I tried installing the rpm file as well but that did not work)
2. How to ask the package manager not to update the zeromq package on update

Note current kernel version

```
 uname -r
 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
```

and Operating sytem

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

Comment: You can use yums [downgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/290596/how-do-i-downgrade-packages-easily-with-yum) or [history undo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856515/yum-downgrade-does-not-remove-new-package) commands.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I removed the `zeromq-4.1.4-5.el7` using yum is there any other I can installed the older version. Plus I'm on a machine where I have only access to running `yum` and `rpm` command rest all command is not allowed for me to access

Comment: Well, the package version you want is so old, it has probably been removed from the mirrors by now. But the pages you linked provide download links for the rpm files. Just download the file for your architecture and install it with `rpm -i`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider tried but it did not install `libzmq.so.3` file whereas the software is looking for `libzmq.so.4`

Comment: Ohh it worked I was installing the `src` tried the `x86_64` and it worked.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider but is there a way I freeze that version the problem happened on 1 of the 2 server (identical server) If I can know how to freeze the specific package I can prevent this from happening on other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package version you want is quite old, it has probably been removed from the mirrors by now.

But the pages you linked provide download links for the rpm files. Just download the file for your architecture (for example: x86_64) and install it with:

```
rpm -i zeromq-4.0.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Is there a way? To freeze that version of a package using yum. The problem happened on 1 of the 2 server (identical server) If I can know how to freeze the specific package I can prevent this from happening on other server

Comment: Sure. Just google for `yum lock version`.